# How to avoid the creation of a new promise for each click?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a click that calls the method:

```
public clickEvent() {
    this.createIframe().then((iframe) => { // Return iframe or create if is not before needed inside 
      // Async hard logic here
    })
}
```

Problem is when user clicks a lot of times `clickEvent()` it fires promise and then fires a hard logic inside.

How to avoid click until logic inside is not finished?
Or disable to call logic inside if it is done?

Comment: Why not create a variable to determine whether you are allowed to run the code or not?

Comment: Like this?

   `if (this.run) return;
    this.run = true;`

Turn back` this.run` to false after execution hard logic

Comment: Yes, absolutely. Additionally, you could also disable the button, then reenable it.

Comment: Why don't you use remove.EventListener("click", clickEvent) at the begining of clickEvent?

Comment: Because it should be clickable but only when hard logic is finished.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you're using Angular, I think you can convert the click event into an observable and then use the variety of operators such as `exhaustMap` to achieve this.

```
import { exhaustMap, fromEvent } from 'rxjs';
....
  @ViewChild('btnId') btnElementRef!: ElementRef<HTMLButtonElement>;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    fromEvent(this.btnElementRef.nativeElement, 'click')
      .pipe(
        exhaustMap(() => this.createIframe())
      )
      .subscribe((iframe) => {
        // hard coded async logic here
      });
  }
);
```

This will ignore sub-sequent click until the Promise resolve first.

Further more, if you want to disable the button and display somekind of loading indicator, you can also add a variable to track that inside the stream using `tap`

```
  fromEvent(this.btnElementRef.nativeElement, 'click')
      .pipe(
        tap(() => isProcessing = true),
        exhaustMap(() => this.createIframe())
      )
      .subscribe((iframe) => {
        isProcessing = false;
        // hard coded async logic here
      });
```

Answer (score -1):

Make `createIframe` cache its Promise (like as an instance property), and return that first if it exists, instead of starting another. For example:

```js
// example function that creates the Promise
const createPromise = () => {
  console.log('creating Promise');
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 3000));
}

class SomeClass {
  createIframe() {
    if (this.iframePromise) return this.iframePromise;
    this.iframePromise = createPromise();
    return this.iframePromise;
  }
  clickEvent() {
    this.createIframe().then((iframe) => {
      console.log('clickEvent has received the Promise and is now running more code');
    })
  }
}

const s = new SomeClass();
button.onclick = () => s.clickEvent();
```

```html
<button id="button">click to call clickEvent</button>
```

If you also want to prevent `// Async hard logic here` from running multiple times after multiple clicks, assign something to the instance inside `clickEvent` instead.

```js
// example function that creates the Promise
const createPromise = () => {
  console.log('creating Promise');
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 3000));
}

class SomeClass {
  createIframe() {
    return createPromise();
  }
  clickEvent() {
    if (this.hasClicked) return;
    this.hasClicked = true;
    this.createIframe().then((iframe) => {
      console.log('clickEvent has received the Promise and is now running more code');
    })
  }
}

const s = new SomeClass();
button.onclick = () => s.clickEvent();
```

```html
<button id="button">click to call clickEvent</button>
```

Comment: The possible solution of yours needs to be adapted to `Angular`,`Typescript`, OP is using that framework.

Comment: I wrote the snippets in JS so that they're runnable, so that all that's needed to demonstrate that it works is to click the button - TS is not runnable in Stack Snippets and is less useful, but it's trivial for OP to add the type annotations